# Ignore case in XSLT

Tags: xslt

this is a general question regarding XSLT, but since I could not find an answer I am asking it here.
Is there a global switch in XSLT which will tell the processor to ignore the case?
I found quite a few examples to conver from lower to upper and vice versa but they all work on individual tag/element level.
I am trying to transform an input xml to another xml, but the input xml tags are not consistent in their semantics so if there is a global switch which can tell the processor to ignore case while doing a match it would reduce a lot of redundant code.

Regards.

Comment: Do you mean the case of XML tag names? I'm sure there shouldn't be such a switch in standard XSLT, since it wouldn't be consistent with XML's semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a global switch in XSLT which will tell the processor to
>   ignore the case?

No. Not only the W3C XSLT Specifications don't specify such a "feature", but if such option did exist, it would really be harmful.

**Consider an XML document like this**:

```
<doc>
 <myTable/>
 <MYTable/>
</doc>
```

This is an XML document in which the top element has *two differently named* elements that quite probably have different type (semantics). Treating these two different elements as if they were of the same type would, in the general case, lead to errors.